# GAE DataStore: query a existing by user_id field

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-account

I have saved the user_id() field and now I want to query the datastore for that user.
How would I go about accomplishing that?

```
#Something like
user = db.Query(MyUser).filter('user.user_id() = ', 1234).fetch(limit=1)
```

Thanks

Comment: I think only variables are supported where you have a function `user.user_id()`. I think you most use a temporary variable to make your query work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create a separate string property to store the user ID, then query for that. The UserProperty class is full of traps and is best avoided.

Answer (score 1):

if what you are searching for is the actual entity Id then you can query for it with the `get_by_id` method

```
user = MyUser.get_by_id(1234)
```

note that if you create it with a parent the you need to pass that to the `get_by_id()` function too.

```
user = MyUser.get_by_id(1234, parent=parent)
```

docs:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/modelclass#Model_get_by_id

Comment: No, I meant that I am saving a User Class instance, that implements the function user_id() and represents a google account. and I store that instance in the datastore, hoping to find it with a query.

Comment: you can't query or filter for function results. do you store the userid as a property in the model? you should update your question with your model, the user_id function and how you save the entity